# Difference between these creation methods? Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a blog where I am creating comments via the following code. I noticed both work in the (seemingly) exact same manner.

Are there any pros and cons to the following two ways of calling this creation method in the view? Are there more ways available to call on such an event?

*`Post` and `Comment` are connected via `has_many` and `belongs_to` relations.*

1. `<%= simple_form_for([@post, Comment.new]) do |f| %>`
2. `<%= simple_form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>`

Here is my comments_controller:

```
def create
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.create(comment_params)
  if @comment.save
    flash[:success] = "Comment created!"
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  else
    flash[:danger] = "Error"
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end
end
```

Comment: Sidenote when you "create" a comment it is already calling `save` is validation passes so `@comment.save` is a second loop through validations and potentially a redundant save operation. Suggestion use `build` instead of `create` then call `save`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there is no real difference between `.new` and `.build` because `build` is an alias for `new`.

You could also put the `build` or `new` in your `new` controller action:

```
def new
  @post = Post.new
  @comment = @post.comment.build
end
```

And then just use the instance variables in your form:

```
<%= simple_form_for([@post, @comment]) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example use-case. Would one be more of a "best practice"? Similar to how rockets (`=>`) were kind of replaced with `:objects`?